# copy file to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

Is there a way to copy a file from my local to S3 bucket by passing I am access keys through command line .Like

```
cp $file_name AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $S3_BUCKETNAME
```

Tried above command but never worked

Answer (score 5):

First, install `awscli` ([documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html)):

```
pip install [--user] awscli
```

Then:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
aws s3 cp <file> <S3Uri>
```

Credentials can also be specified using profiles in the `aws` configuration file ([documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#cli-aws-help-config-vars)):

```
cat <<EOF >~/.aws/config
[profile test1]
aws_access_key_id=foo1
aws_secret_access_key=bar1
[profile test2]
aws_access_key_id=foo2
aws_secret_access_key=bar2
EOF
aws --profile test1 s3 cp <uri1> <file>
aws --profile test2 s3 cp <file> <uri2>
```

Note that:

> Credentials from environment variables have precedence over credentials from the shared credentials and AWS CLI config file.

Thus, to use multiple credential sets, make sure none of them are passed as environment variables, because they would override those from the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the response David ..yes i have  been running this aws s3 cp <file> <S3Uri> from a jenkins job while passing AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
and  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY through environmental variables .But the issue I a facing now is in the script which jenkins contains have to push artifact to another S3 bucket as well..so it is failing to push to another S3 bucket as these access keys are different for both the S3 buckets

Comment: how do we call that specific profile while running cp command ...or will it be taken automatically

Comment: @rreddy: you can use multiple AWS credentials to  multiple S3 bucket. Why not?
By using Jenkins, you can inject multiple AWS as you need. Then

inject Cred1

export Cred1

cp s3bucket1